# Fetching salesforce accounts using rforce gem and bulk api

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, salesforce, bulk-load

How can I fetch multiple records in salesforce with one API call via rforce gem? Also, I know that one API call can fetch maximum 2000 records if my record count is > 2000 (say 20000) how do I iterate and fetch?

Comment: when you run a query that returns more than 2000 records you are given back an iterator token.  You need to call the API's equiv of queryMore and pass back in the token.

Answer (score 2):

There is gem https://rubygems.org/gems/salesforce_bulk_api 
sudo gem install salesforce_bulk_api